# How can I remove input tags from a string using jQuery? This string contains other html tags as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is the string:

Hi`&nbsp;<input type="text" placeholder="Person&nbsp;Full&nbsp;Name">,<span><br></span><span><br></span><span><span>`This is a sample email template for`&nbsp;</span></span><input type="text" placeholder="Deal&nbsp;Title">&nbsp;`associated with`&nbsp;<input type="text" placeholder="Deal&nbsp;Owner"><span><br></span><span><br></span><span><span><br></span></span><span><span><span>`Regards,`</span></span></span><span><span><span><span><br></span></span></span></span><input type="text" placeholder="Organization&nbsp;Name"><span><br></span><span>`dlkgmffkgmkm`&nbsp;</span><input type="text" placeholder="">&nbsp;` dslkfmlgdmglkfnkl `<input type="text" placeholder=""><br>`

I am also using an Editor in my textarea.

```
        $(".btn-removehtml").click(function() {
           html = $('.email-textarea').Editor("getText");
           replaceInput = html.find('input').replaceWith(function() {
                return this.innerHTML;
           }).end().html();
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this..

```
var string = '<input type="text" placeholder="Person&nbsp;Full&nbsp;Name">,<span><br></span><span><br></span><span><span>';

var newString = $(string).not('input');

$('body').append(newString);
```

For all use input you can do this.

```
var newString = $(string).find('input').remove().end();
```

Comment: what kind of syntax error? can you please explain the error.

Comment: it points to $(string). I think it is trying to say that we can't use "$" with string variable in this case...

Comment: just try to remove initial `&nbsp;` from start of your string.

Comment: Just try to remove initial `&nbsp;` from start. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

call the below function to replace the all the input in to static value "abcd"

```
function parseEmailTemplate(html) {
    let myRegex = /<input\s[^>]*>/gi;
    let match = myRegex.exec(html);
    if (match) {
        value="abcd";
        html = html.replace(match[0], value);
        html = parseEmailTemplate(html);
    }
    return html;
}
```